# does breaking inline styling into multiple lines affect anything?

Tags: html, css, inline-styles

let's say I have a very long line of inline styling, for example:

```
<input type="radio" style="visibility: hidden; position: absolute; foo: bar; baz: foo; etcetera: etc; and: more;">
```

and then I decide to make it more readable like this:

```
<input type="radio" style="visibility: hidden; position: absolute;
    foo: bar; baz: foo; etcetera: etc; and: more;">
```

Does this affect the functionality or is it okay to break it into multiple lines like this?

Comment: I'm sure you've heard this before, but avoid inline styles and you won't even have to worry :)

Comment: Yes I have, and I agree. I'm just cleaning up other people's code that's really poorly formatted..it's a nightmare to read and maintain.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's fine. White space doesn't affect the browsers interpretation of that CSS or rendering of that element.

Answer (score 0):

its actually do in img tag

code: [image that show you multiline inline styling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WLAX9.png)

result:
[image that show you result with unwanted special character added to the style](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fB57V.png)

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557